# Strange margin problem in IE6

Tags: html, css, margin, internet-explorer-6

HTML:

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="up">
            This is the up div
        </div>
        <div id="down">
            <h3>This is the down div</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outter{
    height: 400px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #bfd2e1;
}
#left{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#up{
    width: 355px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ffe59f;
    padding: 12px;
    line-height: 16pt;
    margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
}
#down{
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
    width: 381px;
}
#down h3{
    border: 1px solid #bfd2e1;
    background-color: #edf6fe;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The problem is, in Chrome/Firefox, the page looks like:
[image]
but in IE6:
[image]
As you can see, there is a margin problem with `#down`.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wong2/dTEcs/1/
How could that happen?

Comment: Works fine for me using IE8 in IE7 mode (I'll be hanged if I'm ever going to install IE7 again).  Maybe it's a cache problem??

Comment: I have IE7 and it looks just fine - cache would be my first thought too.

Comment: @Brock Adams Oh, I'm sorry, I'm just found out that I'm using IE6...

Comment: @g_thom really sorry but I just found that I'm using IE6

Comment: Then you have two problems :). Sorry, that's no fair, I can at least take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IE6 doubles margins on floated elements](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html).

Add `display: inline` to your floated element (`#down`).